# How to embed output console window inside Qt GUI app?

Tags: c++, c, qt, exec

I am making GUI program in Qt with ready-made command-line operations in forms of buttons, e.g if we want to extract zips using 7z standalone 7z.exe we type

`7z.exe -x -tzip a.zip`

I am doing GUI of this, then my question is how I can embed that black command prompt style console inside Qt GUI app itself to display whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

Use **QProcess**:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#details

(This is a 180° edit. You can find my other answer in the history…)

Comment: But how? Can you give an example to embed it?

Comment: It is not about embedding a console to the GUI. Use QProcess to execute 7zip and read the output using readAllStandardOutput(). Then write the output to QListWidget or QTextEdit which you can style to use black background and white text.